# AndroidStudio keeps data from old active sessions and transfers them to the new active session

Tags: android-studio

While debugging with Android Studio I have noticed two problems:

1. Old inputs in the EditText field (previous active and debugging session inputs) are actually appended to any new input during debugging (so I get some historical data + newly inputted data).
2. Sometimes my program just crashes without any reason when I press the button (setOnClickListener) -> fails to execute. Then I need to place dbg in that function and everything starts working. Strange.

I believe I have some problems with cashed data in the simulator, maybe? Do you know what I should do?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.type.watch" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".windows.Win1Activity"></activity>
    <activity android:name=".windows.Win2Activity" />
    <activity android:name=".windows.Win3Activity" />
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: Can you provide the application declaration in your AndroidManifest.xml file?

Comment: Yes. I have added it.